# How can a shell script control another script

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I remember vaguely a technique using pipes for communication between two shell processes.

Are there any tutorials available on how to setup and control a subshell?

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you are trying to accomplish? If you just trying to autopilot a subprocess, expect might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [Advanced Bash Scripting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) guide?

There's an entire [chapter](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) about - surprise surprise - subshells.

Comment: @sm - thanks I knows this guide, but my problem is rather how to communicate between the processes

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't read your question carefully enough.
How about this http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about [named pipes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/extmisc.html#MKFIFOREF)?

```
mkfifo pipe
ls -l >pipe #type this is one shell
cat <pipe #type this is another one
```

No one reads if no one writes.
No one writes if no one reads.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going, examples are in C, but the same technique applies to bash. Just do a search for named pipes, in google or here, alot of examples specific to bash pops up.

http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/named_pipes.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you want coprocesses.  In bash 4 there is a new builtin "coproc".

See here for examples:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html